# JSON: encode, parse, render table using Javascript > jsfiddle example not working

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/snowweb/7FDFW/7/), which I'm using to get my concept working.

It's likely that the issues I'm having are caused by the JSON, I'll share the code I use to generate that.

First I do a query:

```
$sth->execute();

$last_sup   = 0;
$i          = 0;
$reorderArr = array();
$prodsArr   = array();
$si         = 0;

while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {

    // If new supplier.
    if ($last_sup !== $row->sup_id) {

        $last_sup = $row->sup_id;

        // If not first iteration.
        if ($i !== 0) {

            // Append $prodsArr to current $supArr
            $supArr['prods'] = (array)$prodsArr;

            // empty $prodsArr ready for next sup.
            $prodsArr = array();

            // Append $supArr to previous $reorderArr
            $reorderArr[$si] = (array)$supArr;

            $si++;
        }

        // Create entries for new supplier to $supArr
        $supArr = array(
            "supID"                 => $row->sup_id,
            "supName"               => $row->supplier_comp_name
        );
    }

    // Build array of products for this supplier.
    $prodsArr[] = array(
        "pID"                   => $row->prod_id,
        "sku"                   => $row->sku,
        "pName"                 => $row->prod_name,
        "cat"                   => $row->category_name,
        "desc"                  => $row->prod_desc,
        "stock_level"           => $row->stock_level,
        "reOrdLev"              => $row->reorder_level,
        "reOrdQty"              => $row->reorder_qty,
        "vat_exempt"            => $row->vat_exempt,
        "lastorderdate"         => $row->lastorderdate,
        "lastorderqty"          => $row->lastorderqty,
        "qty_in_outer"          => $row->qty_in_outer,
        "cost_per_outer"        => $row->cost_per_outer
    );

    $i++;

}

// Process the very last loop (since it's normally processed
// at the start of the next loop.

// Append $prodsArr to current $supArr
$supArr[] = (array)$prodsArr;

// Append $supArr to previous $reorderArr
$reorderArr[$si] = (array)$supArr;


return $reorderArr;
```

Then I **double** `json_encode` it (because the tutorial I followed told me to) and parse it with Jquery like so:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(<? print json_encode(json_encode($reorderArr));?>);
```

and I include the line above between script tags on my page and send it to my function for processing it using the line below:

```
displayReorderList(data);
```

Here is the `displayReorderList()` function in it's current state:

```
function displayReorderList($data) {

    var table = document.createElement('table');

    /**
     * Set up supplier group.
     * 1 loop per group.
     */
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');  
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');

        // Need to put the Supplier name here in a colspan cell.
        var text1 = document.createTextNode(data[i].supName);
        td1.appendChild(text1);
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        table.appendChild(tr);

        /**
         * Setup Product Group.
         * 1 loop per product.
         */
        for(var j = 0; j < data[i].prods.length; j++) {

            var tr = document.createElement('tr');  
            var td1 = document.createElement('td');

            var text1 = document.createTextNode(data[i].prods[j].sku);
            td1.appendChild(text1);
            tr.appendChild(td1);
            table.appendChild(tr);

        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(table);
```

To give an easy overview of the data structure, here is a `print_r($reorderArr)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [supID] => 2
            [supName] => Sparks
            [prods] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [pID] => 7
                            [sku] => 7
                            [pName] => Term Block
                            [cat] => Electrical
                            [desc] => Nylon connector block.
                            [stock_level] => 3
                            [reOrdLev] => 5
                            [reOrdQty] => 20
                            [vat_exempt] => 0
                            [lastorderdate] => 
                            [lastorderqty] => 
                            [qty_in_outer] => 1
                            [cost_per_outer] => 60.00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [pID] => 5
                            [sku] => 5
                            [pName] => Electrical Tape
                            [cat] => Electrical
                            [desc] => Black
                            [stock_level] => 12
                            [reOrdLev] => 20
                            [reOrdQty] => 100
                            [vat_exempt] => 0
                            [lastorderdate] => 
                            [lastorderqty] => 
                            [qty_in_outer] => 1
                            [cost_per_outer] => 39.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [supID] => 9
            [supName] => Prime Plumbing Inc.
            [prods] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [pID] => 6
                            [sku] => 6
                            [pName] => BlowGas
                            [cat] => Plumbing
                            [desc] => 400g Canister
                            [stock_level] => 6
                            [reOrdLev] => 15
                            [reOrdQty] => 60
                            [vat_exempt] => 0
                            [lastorderdate] => 
                            [lastorderqty] => 
                            [qty_in_outer] => 1
                            [cost_per_outer] => 142.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [supID] => 12
            [supName] => Trade Plumbing Supplies Inc.
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [pID] => 1
                            [sku] => 1
                            [pName] => PTFE Tape
                            [cat] => Plumbing
                            [desc] => 10mm x 3m
                            [stock_level] => 9
                            [reOrdLev] => 10
                            [reOrdQty] => 50
                            [vat_exempt] => 0
                            [lastorderdate] => 
                            [lastorderqty] => 
                            [qty_in_outer] => 1
                            [cost_per_outer] => 24
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [pID] => 14
                            [sku] => 14
                            [pName] => Antique Tap Set
                            [cat] => Plumbing
                            [desc] => Gold/Ceramic bathroom set.
                            [stock_level] => 2
                            [reOrdLev] => 2
                            [reOrdQty] => 3
                            [vat_exempt] => 0
                            [lastorderdate] => 
                            [lastorderqty] => 
                            [qty_in_outer] => 1
                            [cost_per_outer] => 2800.00
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'm attempting to end up with a lists of products which have reached their reorder levels, grouped by supplier but the the script seems to be stalling at `for(var j = 0; j < data[i].prods.length; j++) {` but only after iterating past that line several times. It seems like the length of `data[i].prods` is being incorrectly reported, maybe because the JSON is malformed?

Please see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snowweb/7FDFW/7/).

**UPDATE**
I've updated as follows, after @Yogesh pointed me in the right direction.

I have changed `$supArr[] = (array)$prodsArr;` to `$supArr[prods] = (array)$prodsArr;` in the server-side array construction.

After doing that, it all worked nicely. See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/snowweb/7FDFW/10/) with the correctly generated data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your array's third element doesn't contains `prods` array see here

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [supID] => 12
        [supName] => Trade Plumbing Supplies Inc.
        [0] => Array
         ^// its 0 not prods

[1] => Array
    (
        [supID] => 9
        [supName] => Prime Plumbing Inc.
        [prods] => Array
           ^// its prods
```

and because of that the length of data[i].prods is being incorrectly reported.

You have `if` condition here and because of that `prods` is not available for all array

```
if ($i !== 0) {

        // Append $prodsArr to current $supArr
        $supArr['prods'] = (array)$prodsArr;
```

Comment: Well done for spotting that, although actually, the intention was to use [prods] rather than numeric index, so I need to (a) figure out why it's not consistent and (b) make it always use [prods].